# Regular expression to extract words that starts with a pattern, but ends before symbols or spaces

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyverse, stringr

I have the following example **with `proc` as a regex**:

```
x <- "carr proc proc_ proca select procb() procth;"
pattern <- "proc"
```

The expected result would be

```
"proc" "proca" "procb" "procth"
```

could be a list or a vector.

I tried several other regex with **stringr::str_extract_all**, but could not get all the words that I wanted.

Comment: `pattern <- "\\bproc\\w*"`

Comment: No, that wouldn't give the expected output nor does the dupe link

Comment: Try `str_extract_all(x, "\\bproc([a-z]+|\\b)")[[1]]#
[1] "proc"   "proca"  "procb"  "procth"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```r
pattern <- "\\bproc[[:alnum:]]*\\b"
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/781vGI/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  proc                     'proc'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [[:alnum:]]*             any character of: letters and digits (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
> unique(agrep(pattern, unlist(strsplit(x, "[^[:alpha:]]+")), value = TRUE))
[1] "proc"   "proca"  "procb"  "procth"
```